# how do make the image of TreeNode display smaller?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

In my windows form I have the following `Treeview` control with four nodes to represent the academic years of a university program.

[image]

As you can see I have added small images to the nodes (to color code them) image are of size 8 X 8 pixels png images. I have used the `ImageList` collection to store them inline.

there are two issues I have with this

1. there is no gap between the nodes so the images (the color codes) don't look professional

the second problem refer to the following image to see what happened when I click a node

[image]

2.As you can see the green one suddenly got orange

is there a way to fix those problems?

in the current configuration of the `treeview` control, I have set the `showlines` to `false` and `hideselection` to `false` all the rest of properties are their default settings.

here is the code

in the form's load() I have this `myImageList` collection variable is globally declared

```
    private void FrmNewProgram_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myImageList = new ImageList();
        myImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(SMSV100.Properties.Resources.year1tagx16));
        myImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(SMSV100.Properties.Resources.year12tagx16));
        myImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(SMSV100.Properties.Resources.year3x16));
        myImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(SMSV100.Properties.Resources.year4x16));
        tvcAcdYears.ImageList = myImageList;
   }
```

There is combobox which I did not mentioned but here what it does, it has 1, 2, 3, 4 values respectively mean year 1, 2, 3, 4 so in the SelectedIndexChanged() event of the combobox I have added this code so it will add the nodes in the following way. if the user selects 1, adds only Year #1 to the TreeView if user selects 2, adds Year #1 and Year #2 to the treeview so forth

```
 private void cmbProgDuration_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbProgDuration.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            if (cmbProgDuration.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Clear();
                TreeNode tnOneYear = new TreeNode("Year #1");


                tnOneYear.ImageIndex = 0;
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tnOneYear);


            }
            else if (cmbProgDuration.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Clear();
                TreeNode tnOneYear = new TreeNode("Year #1");
                tnOneYear.ImageIndex = 0;


                TreeNode tn2ndYear = new TreeNode("Year #2");
                tn2ndYear.ImageIndex = 1;


                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tnOneYear);
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tn2ndYear);
            }
            else if (cmbProgDuration.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Clear();
                TreeNode tnOneYear = new TreeNode("Year #1");
                tnOneYear.ImageIndex = 0;


                TreeNode tn2ndYear = new TreeNode("Year #2");
                tn2ndYear.ImageIndex = 1;


                TreeNode tn3rdYear = new TreeNode("Year #3");
                tn3rdYear.ImageIndex = 2;


                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tnOneYear);
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tn2ndYear);
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tn3rdYear);
            }
            else if (cmbProgDuration.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Clear();
                TreeNode tnOneYear = new TreeNode("Year #1");
                tnOneYear.ImageIndex = 0;                    


                TreeNode tn2ndYear = new TreeNode("Year #2");
                tn2ndYear.ImageIndex = 1;


                TreeNode tn3rdYear = new TreeNode("Year #3");
                tn3rdYear.ImageIndex = 2;


                TreeNode tn4thYear = new TreeNode("Year #4");
                tn4thYear.ImageIndex = 3;


                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tnOneYear);
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tn2ndYear);
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tn3rdYear);
                tvcAcdYears.Nodes.Add(tn4thYear);
            }

            tvcAcdYears.SelectedNode = tvcAcdYears.Nodes[0];

        }
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change images to have size 16x16 and for each of them put original 8x8 image to the center, keeping edge transparent.
2. Make sure that the `SelectedImageIndex` property (and the `StateImageIndex` if the `StateImage` property is set) of each treeview's node is set to the same value as for the `ImageIndex` property.